# Enabling mp4/mpeg4/avc support for Qt5 WebEngine on Linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu, ffmpeg, mp4, chromium

i installed Qt 5.4.1 x64 on LUbuntu and created an app which uses the new QtWebEngine.

I`m trying to display a html5 page with that component which is using the  tag. 
All works fine except if I try to playback a mp4 video. The video area remains black. It works if I use other video types like webm/ogg as source.

I know this is due to license restrictions, so that mp4 is deactivated by default in Ubuntu/Linux for Qt.

What is needed in Qt to activate it to allow mp4 playback and on what do I have pay attention in case of license terms (I read that statically linking the library is allowed?) ?

I`ve already tried to copy over the x64 distribution of libffmpegsuo.so which is included in Chrome (2,2Mb) over to the Qt directory to /plugins/webengine/ and replaced that one that was already there (1,1 Mb) but it had no effect.
In Chrome playback works fine btw.

If you need more details like paths etc. please tell me.

Thanks !

Comment: Here is a corresponding jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tj1e1kpn/   was not able to playback it with the QuickFancyBrowser example included in qt. With chrome binary itself it worked on the same machine (lubuntu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly enable proprietary codecs (H264, MP3) when compiling Qt WebEngine:

In /path-to-qt-src-dir/qtwebengine execute:

```
qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs
```

You should be able to see in the output that H264 codec is enabled, which is not the default configuration.

Comment: Just a tip: qmake has to be run before .configure I think, that was my fault :-)

Comment: When compiling Qt WebEngine itself. That is, if the system Qt WebEngine does not enable them, you've to get the sources of qtwebengine (e.g. via git: code.qt.io/qt/qtwebengine.git) and compile it yourself.

Comment: @kkoehne: Here is what I did. I installed Qt 5.6 version I made & installed it. Then I recompiled the qtwebengine in the src directory with the following commands.  1) qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs 2) make 3) sudo make install. But I tested it with html5 page and it showed me, H 264 is still not supported. Do you have any suggestions or corrections for me?

Comment: I am sorry, how to get that qmake.exe ? Im working on Pyqt5