# Make mp4/h264 video work in QtWebEngine on Windows

Tags: html, video, visual-studio-2013, qt5, qtwebengine

When I point the QtWebEngine instance at a html5 test page (http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html) I see the WebM video, the Theora video, but not H.264/MP4.

[Enabling mp4/mpeg4/avc support for Qt5 WebEngine on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981666/enabling-mp4-mpeg4-avc-support-for-qt5-webengine-on-linux) said to build qtwebengine from source, so I'm building everything.

I downloaded this source package:
http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0.zip

I followed the directions for other dependencies, and then tried building with these commands:

```
configure -prefix %QT_ROOT%\build -opengl dynamic -release -nomake examples -opensource -confirm-license  -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -openssl -qt-pcre -no-cups -no-dbus -skip qtwebkit -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdoc -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -skip qtquick1 -skip qt3d -skip qtwebengine
nmake
nmake install
cd qtwebengine
..\build\bin\qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs qtwebengine.pro
nmake
nmake install
```

Then when I build the web browser example against my new build, I get the same results as before.  When I try to look for evidence that it did or didn't build the codecs, I see that ffmpegsumo.dll was created. I see no errors in the javascript console about this.  I've tested with other test web pages beyond quicksmode and no results there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to upgrade to Qt 5.6.1.  Otherwise, I followed the directions in the original question and this time got a working result.  Most notable, the `qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs` did confirm it was checking and configuring h264 and mp3.

Comment: How to do it without qmake

Comment: The short answer is that building qtwebengine without qmake is not possible because the Qt project doesn't provide any alternative build script files.  The long answer is that you could choose to port the qmake files to something like cmake. The long answer probably isn't helpful, but I hate when people say something is not possible when clearly it is only a very large amount of work.