# Pyqt5 Activate Proprietary codecs

Tags: html, pyqt, mp4, qwebengineview

Currently I am using Pyqt5, QWebEngine. When I try to open my HTML5 `<video>` it does not work.

I know that problem is that I have not activated Proprietary codecs.

Look at this solution: [Make mp4/h264 video work in QtWebEngine on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847968/make-mp4-h264-video-work-in-qtwebengine-on-windows)

I tried `-proprietary-codecs` as QApplication argument but it did not work.

Comment: Please add all errors you are getting.

Comment: There is no evidence in that answer that `-proprietary-codecs` is a QApplication argument. Obviously you need to read it again and try to understand it properly.

Comment: My question is about activation that codecs. Thank you. I cant run Facebook videos because it says: This cant be run on this browser/platform. Also, i get some more errors but they are different, e.g: PIP_MEDIA_ERROR

Comment: Was this problem ever solved? I am using PyQt 5.14.2 and having the same issues. Thanks

Comment: This issue died with my project, i do not think its fixed. You have to use c++ to compile qt with proprietary codecs as i know.

Answer (score 0):

you need enable it as chromium flag `--enable-features=-webengine-proprietary-codecs`[...](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs)

Comment: That would be trough C++ not python. Is that right?

Comment: Nah its chromium flag

Comment: It's not a chromium flag, it's Qt build flag. You need to complie it yourself to enable it.