# pyqt5 5.8.2 Vimeo video playback fails

Tags: python, video, pyqt5

The following code works for me on the latest Ubuntu, but when I try to isolate it in a virtual environment I get a "This video can’t be played with your current setup." error when trying to play a video.

I get the same error on Windows 10 as well.

Videos from YouTube play fine.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWebEngineView()
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('http://vimeo.com'))
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

pip freeze shows the following:

```
pkg-resources==0.0.0
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
PyQt5==5.8.2
sip==4.19.2
```

Is there some other package I need to pip install?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a near duplicate of [Enabling mp4/mpeg4/avc support for Qt5 WebEngine on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981666/enabling-mp4-mpeg4-avc-support-for-qt5-webengine-on-linux).

Is there an API to determine which codecs are available?  I'm guessing the pyqt5 supplied by Ubuntu has codec support that the pypi version does not.